# How to access variables outside of class in PHP?

Tags: php

I am creating a simple login form for test and I created two class 'Connection' and 'Validate' for connection and login validation respectively. But the problem is i am not able to use the $conn i.e. variable for PDO Connection in Validate class. I heard that using globals is bad practice so please help me how can i access variable outside of class.

conn.init.php(CONNECTION FILE)

```
<?php

    class Connection{

    public function connect(){

        try{
        session_start();    
        $conns = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $conns;
    }
}
```

And validate.php(Login Validation):

```
<?php

include('conn.init.php')

class Validate extends Connection{

    private $conn;
    public $emails = null;
    public $passwords = null;

   //Here's problem
    public function __construct(Connection $conns){
        $this->conn = $conns;
    }

    public function login($email, $password){
        $query = "SELECT email, password FROM login WHERE email = :email AND password = :password";
        $query_run = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $query_run->bindParam('email', $email);
        $query_run->bindParam('password', $password);
        $query_run->execute();
        $rows = $query_run->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($rows as $row){
            $this->emails = $row['email'];
            $this->passwords = $row['password'];
        }

        if($email === $this->emails && $password === $this->passwords){
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$user = new Validate;  //What's should i do here?
$user->connect();      //What's should i do here?
```

LIKE THIS! 
[image: HOW TO USE APPLE VARIABLE IN OTHER CLASS?]

Comment: declare `$conn` outside `try` block

Comment: But why doesn't it work? Let me post full code. Please wait @TobyAllen

Comment: Your picture doesn't make sense. 1) `$apple` in the `Apple#foo` method is locally scoped to that method only. 2) Whatever you pass to the `Mango` constructor is assigned to its `bar` property, eg `$someString = 'this is a string'; $mango = new Mango($someString);`... the `$mango` private `bar` property is now `"this is a string"`. I don't see a connection between the two classes at all

Comment: @Phil You are really not understanding me! Like there' s a function called foo where apple is global(global $apple) and to pass this $apple in other function bar we use global $apple in bar too, right! In this way we can pass variable from one function to other. But how can we pass variable from one class to other class. That's my question!

Comment: @Phil please see the edited comment. I think i am consuming your time :(

Comment: In php, depending on how you declare the class, you can reference a class variable like this:  $obj->var.  This is not a good practice, and it only works if the class variable is public, which used to be the way things were back in the php 3-4 days.  But that practice goes against good oop design.  When you want to return something you should have a getter (getSomething) method and return the value of the variable that way.  Also in php5 all objects are passed by reference, so if the thing is an object, returning it will return the actual object. PHP uses references to keep this straight.

Comment: Good OOP design is a science and an art.  Most of the quality libraries out there that involve significant OOP design, are utilizing OOP design patterns.  There are entire books on the subject, from the "Gang of Four" book, to specific books and sites on Design patterns in PHP.  I also think if you read this series it might help your thinking about how to approach what you are trying to do now:  http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @gview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Connection` is a completely useless class and you'll probably accidentally attempt to create multiple `PDO` instances if you continue using it.
2. If an exception occurs while connecting to your database, **do not** continue to execute your program as if it worked.
3. Pass a `PDO` instance to your `Validate` class. It appears this is what you wanted to do anyway

   ```
   class Validate {
       private $conn;

       public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
           $this->conn = $pdo;
       }

       // etc
   }

   session_start();    
   $conns = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'root', '', [
       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
   ]);
   $user = new Validate($conns);
   ```

---

Your DB query is doing some very strange things. If you just want to check the existence of a record matching `$email` and `$password`, this is simpler

```
public function login($email, $password){
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM `login` WHERE `email` = :email AND `password` = :password";
    $query_run = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $query_run->execute([
        ':email' => $email,
        ':password' => $password
    ]);
    if ($query_run->fetchColumn()) {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you haven't already, make sure `email` has a unique constraint and please **do not** store plain-text passwords in your database.

Comment: Thank you! Your code works but let's say i am not using pdo class rather using other class. Then how can i access variable of one class to other?

Comment: @Bill Not sure what you're asking. You should make your question as clear as possible. If you're not using PDO, then why use it in your question?

Comment: For now i am using pdo though! If so, then i will ask this thing in other question. Thanks a lot! Marked as answer.

Comment: @Bill as you an see, passing the `PDO` instance `$conns` to the `Validate` constructor and storing it in `$conn` allows you access to public methods (and properties) like `$this->conn->prepare(...)`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yup That's it! Please tell me how can i do this?

Comment: @Bill err, didn't I just show you? I really don't understand what your question is

Comment: OK! Please wait! I am gonna post a picture! @Phil

Comment: please see the picture!